# java.lang.VerifyError: class org.elasticsearch.index.search.MatchQuery$MatchQueryBuilder overrides final method createFieldQuery

Tags: java, maven, elasticsearch, neo4j, verifyerror

I want to use elasticsearch in neo4j custom plugin. For this, I have following in my pom entry:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
        <artifactId>transport</artifactId>
        <version>6.2.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

I am connecting to elasticsearch through following code:

```
private  ElasticSearchBase() throws UnknownHostException {
    Config config = Config.getInstance();
    String clusterName = config.properties.getProperty(ES_CLUSTER_NAME);
    String host = config.properties.getProperty(ES_HOST);
    int port = Integer.valueOf(config.properties.getProperty(ES_PORT));

    Settings settings = Settings.builder().put("cluster.name", clusterName).build();
    client = new PreBuiltTransportClient(settings).addTransportAddress(
            new TransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName(host), port));
    LOG.info("Connection to elastic server successfully: "+client.toString());
}
```

While running neo4j, I am getting following error:

```
2018-05-28 13:40:09.116+0000 ERROR Failed to start Neo4j: Starting Neo4j failed: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@4f1d97d8' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see the attached cause exception "class org.elasticsearch.index.search.MatchQuery$MatchQueryBuilder overrides final method createFieldQuery.(Lorg/apache/lucene/analysis/Analyzer;Lorg/apache/lucene/search/BooleanClause$Occur;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;ZI)Lorg/apache/lucene/search/Query;". Starting Neo4j failed: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@4f1d97d8' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see the attached cause exception "class org.elasticsearch.index.search.MatchQuery$MatchQueryBuilder overrides final method createFieldQuery.(Lorg/apache/lucene/analysis/Analyzer;Lorg/apache/lucene/search/BooleanClause$Occur;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;ZI)Lorg/apache/lucene/search/Query;".
org.neo4j.server.ServerStartupException: Starting Neo4j failed: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@4f1d97d8' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see the attached cause exception "class org.elasticsearch.index.search.MatchQuery$MatchQueryBuilder overrides final method createFieldQuery.(Lorg/apache/lucene/analysis/Analyzer;Lorg/apache/lucene/search/BooleanClause$Occur;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;ZI)Lorg/apache/lucene/search/Query;".
    at org.neo4j.server.exception.ServerStartupErrors.translateToServerStartupError(ServerStartupErrors.java:68)
    at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:219)
    at org.neo4j.server.ServerBootstrapper.start(ServerBootstrapper.java:111)
    at org.neo4j.server.ServerBootstrapper.start(ServerBootstrapper.java:79)
    at org.neo4j.server.CommunityEntryPoint.main(CommunityEntryPoint.java:32)
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@4f1d97d8' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see the attached cause exception "class org.elasticsearch.index.search.MatchQuery$MatchQueryBuilder overrides final method createFieldQuery.(Lorg/apache/lucene/analysis/Analyzer;Lorg/apache/lucene/search/BooleanClause$Occur;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;ZI)Lorg/apache/lucene/search/Query;".
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:466)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:107)
    at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:211)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error starting org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory, /home/gaurav_verma/.ineo/instances/staging2/data/databases/graph.db
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.initFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:211)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.newFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:126)
    at org.neo4j.server.CommunityNeoServer.lambda$static$0(CommunityNeoServer.java:58)
    at org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase.start(LifecycleManagingDatabase.java:88)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:445)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.impl.proc.Procedures@6fbe879b' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see the attached cause exception "class org.elasticsearch.index.search.MatchQuery$MatchQueryBuilder overrides final method createFieldQuery.(Lorg/apache/lucene/analysis/Analyzer;Lorg/apache/lucene/search/BooleanClause$Occur;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;ZI)Lorg/apache/lucene/search/Query;".
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:466)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:107)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.initFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:207)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: class org.elasticsearch.index.search.MatchQuery$MatchQueryBuilder overrides final method createFieldQuery.(Lorg/apache/lucene/analysis/Analyzer;Lorg/apache/lucene/search/BooleanClause$Occur;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;ZI)Lorg/apache/lucene/search/Query;
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:411)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.proc.ProcedureJarLoader$1.fetchNextOrNull(ProcedureJarLoader.java:141)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.proc.ProcedureJarLoader$1.fetchNextOrNull(ProcedureJarLoader.java:118)
    at org.neo4j.collection.PrefetchingRawIterator.peek(PrefetchingRawIterator.java:50)
    at org.neo4j.collection.PrefetchingRawIterator.hasNext(PrefetchingRawIterator.java:36)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.proc.ProcedureJarLoader.loadProcedures(ProcedureJarLoader.java:91)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.proc.ProcedureJarLoader.loadProceduresFromDir(ProcedureJarLoader.java:82)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.proc.Procedures.start(Procedures.java:275)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:445)
    ... 11 more
```

I tried with different versions of elasticsearch but every time I get some error of this sort. Can anyone tell me what is the issue here and how to resolve it? When running mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose, I am getting following dependency tree:

```
[INFO] +- org.elasticsearch.client:transport:jar:6.2.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch:jar:6.2.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch-core:jar:6.2.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- (org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.9.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-core:jar:7.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-analyzers-common:jar:7.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-backward-codecs:jar:7.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-grouping:jar:7.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-highlighter:jar:7.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-join:jar:7.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-memory:jar:7.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-misc:jar:7.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-queries:jar:7.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-queryparser:jar:7.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-sandbox:jar:7.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-spatial:jar:7.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-spatial-extras:jar:7.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-spatial3d:jar:7.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-suggest:jar:7.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.elasticsearch:securesm:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch-cli:jar:6.2.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- net.sf.jopt-simple:jopt-simple:jar:5.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.carrotsearch:hppc:jar:0.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.9.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.17:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.8.10:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-smile:jar:2.8.10:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-yaml:jar:2.8.10:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-cbor:jar:2.8.10:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.tdunning:t-digest:jar:3.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.hdrhistogram:HdrHistogram:jar:2.1.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.9.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.elasticsearch:jna:jar:4.5.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.elasticsearch.plugin:transport-netty4-client:jar:6.2.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.netty:netty-buffer:jar:4.1.16.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.netty:netty-codec:jar:4.1.16.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.netty:netty-codec-http:jar:4.1.16.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.netty:netty-common:jar:4.1.16.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.netty:netty-handler:jar:4.1.16.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.netty:netty-resolver:jar:4.1.16.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.netty:netty-transport:jar:4.1.16.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch:jar:6.2.4:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- org.locationtech.spatial4j:spatial4j:jar:0.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.vividsolutions:jts:jar:1.13:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.9.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:jar:2.9.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.elasticsearch:jna:jar:4.5.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- org.elasticsearch.plugin:reindex-client:jar:6.2.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.elasticsearch.client:elasticsearch-rest-client:jar:6.2.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.2:compile - omitted for conflict with 4.5.1)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.5:compile - omitted for conflict with 4.4.3)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpasyncclient:jar:4.1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore-nio:jar:4.4.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.10:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.9)
[INFO] |  |  |  \- (commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.3:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.2)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch:jar:6.2.4:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.locationtech.spatial4j:spatial4j:jar:0.6:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (com.vividsolutions:jts:jar:1.13:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.9.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:jar:2.9.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.elasticsearch:jna:jar:4.5.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- org.elasticsearch.plugin:lang-mustache-client:jar:6.2.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.github.spullara.mustache.java:compiler:jar:0.9.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch:jar:6.2.4:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.locationtech.spatial4j:spatial4j:jar:0.6:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (com.vividsolutions:jts:jar:1.13:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.9.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:jar:2.9.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.elasticsearch:jna:jar:4.5.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- org.elasticsearch.plugin:percolator-client:jar:6.2.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch:jar:6.2.4:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.locationtech.spatial4j:spatial4j:jar:0.6:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (com.vividsolutions:jts:jar:1.13:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.9.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:jar:2.9.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.elasticsearch:jna:jar:4.5.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- org.elasticsearch.plugin:parent-join-client:jar:6.2.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch:jar:6.2.4:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.locationtech.spatial4j:spatial4j:jar:0.6:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (com.vividsolutions:jts:jar:1.13:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.9.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:jar:2.9.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.elasticsearch:jna:jar:4.5.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  \- org.elasticsearch.plugin:rank-eval-client:jar:6.2.4:compile
[INFO] |     +- (org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch:jar:6.2.4:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |     +- (org.locationtech.spatial4j:spatial4j:jar:0.6:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |     +- (com.vividsolutions:jts:jar:1.13:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |     +- (org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.9.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |     +- (org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:jar:2.9.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |     \- (org.elasticsearch:jna:jar:4.5.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- org.neo4j:neo4j:jar:3.1.4:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-kernel:jar:3.1.4:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-graphdb-api:jar:3.1.4:provided
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (org.neo4j:neo4j-common:jar:3.1.4:provided - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-resource:jar:3.1.4:provided
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (org.neo4j:neo4j-collections:jar:3.1.4:provided - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  \- (org.neo4j:neo4j-primitive-collections:jar:3.1.4:provided - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-common:jar:3.1.4:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-collections:jar:3.1.4:provided
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (org.neo4j:neo4j-resource:jar:3.1.4:provided - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  \- (org.neo4j:neo4j-common:jar:3.1.4:provided - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-primitive-collections:jar:3.1.4:provided
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-unsafe:jar:3.1.4:provided
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (org.neo4j:neo4j-common:jar:3.1.4:provided - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  \- (org.neo4j:neo4j-resource:jar:3.1.4:provided - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-io:jar:3.1.4:provided
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (org.neo4j:neo4j-unsafe:jar:3.1.4:provided - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (org.neo4j:neo4j-primitive-collections:jar:3.1.4:provided - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  \- (org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.3.2:provided - omitted for conflict with 3.5)
[INFO] |  |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-csv:jar:3.1.4:provided
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (org.neo4j:neo4j-primitive-collections:jar:3.1.4:provided - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  \- (org.neo4j:neo4j-collections:jar:3.1.4:provided - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-logging:jar:3.1.4:provided
[INFO] |  |  |  \- (org.neo4j:neo4j-io:jar:3.1.4:provided - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  \- org.neo4j:neo4j-lucene-upgrade:jar:3.1.4:provided
[INFO] |  |     +- (org.apache.lucene:lucene-core:jar:5.5.0:provided - omitted for conflict with 7.2.1)
[INFO] |  |     \- (org.apache.lucene:lucene-backward-codecs:jar:5.5.0:provided - omitted for conflict with 7.2.1)
[INFO] |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-lucene-index:jar:3.1.4:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.neo4j:neo4j-kernel:jar:3.1.4:provided - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.apache.lucene:lucene-analyzers-common:jar:5.5.0:provided - omitted for conflict with 7.2.1)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.apache.lucene:lucene-core:jar:5.5.0:provided - omitted for conflict with 7.2.1)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.apache.lucene:lucene-queryparser:jar:5.5.0:provided - omitted for conflict with 7.2.1)
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.lucene:lucene-codecs:jar:5.5.0:provided
[INFO] |  |     \- (org.apache.lucene:lucene-core:jar:5.5.0:provided - omitted for conflict with 7.2.1)
[INFO] |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-graph-algo:jar:3.1.4:provided
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.neo4j:neo4j-kernel:jar:3.1.4:provided - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-udc:jar:3.1.4:provided
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.neo4j:neo4j-kernel:jar:3.1.4:provided - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-graph-matching:jar:3.1.4:provided
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.neo4j:neo4j-kernel:jar:3.1.4:provided - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-cypher:jar:3.1.4:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- org.scala-lang:scala-library:jar:2.11.8:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- org.scala-lang:scala-reflect:jar:2.11.8:provided
[INFO] |  |  |  \- (org.scala-lang:scala-library:jar:2.11.8:provided - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.neo4j:neo4j-kernel:jar:3.1.4:provided - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.neo4j:neo4j-lucene-index:jar:3.1.4:provided - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.neo4j:neo4j-graph-matching:jar:3.1.4:provided - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.neo4j:neo4j-graph-algo:jar:3.1.4:provided - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-codegen:jar:3.1.4:provided
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:5.0.4:compile - scope updated from provided; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  \- (org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.3.2:provided - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-cypher-compiler-2.3:jar:2.3.10:provided
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (org.scala-lang:scala-reflect:jar:2.11.7:provided - omitted for conflict with 2.11.8)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-cypher-frontend-2.3:jar:2.3.10:provided
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- (org.scala-lang:scala-reflect:jar:2.11.7:provided - omitted for conflict with 2.11.8)
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- (org.parboiled:parboiled-scala_2.11:jar:1.1.7:provided - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- (org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.3.2:provided - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (org.parboiled:parboiled-scala_2.11:jar:1.1.7:provided - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.googlecode.concurrentlinkedhashmap:concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru:jar:1.4.2:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-cypher-compiler-3.0:jar:3.0.9:provided
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-cypher-frontend-3.0:jar:3.0.9:provided
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- (org.parboiled:parboiled-scala_2.11:jar:1.1.7:provided - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- (org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.3.2:provided - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  \- (org.parboiled:parboiled-scala_2.11:jar:1.1.7:provided - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-cypher-compiler-3.1:jar:3.1.4:provided
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-cypher-frontend-3.1:jar:3.1.4:provided
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- (org.parboiled:parboiled-scala_2.11:jar:1.1.7:provided - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- (org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.3.2:provided - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (org.parboiled:parboiled-scala_2.11:jar:1.1.7:provided - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.github.ben-manes.caffeine:caffeine:jar:2.3.3:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- org.parboiled:parboiled-scala_2.11:jar:1.1.7:provided
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.parboiled:parboiled-core:jar:1.1.7:provided
[INFO] |  |  \- net.sf.opencsv:opencsv:jar:2.3:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-jmx:jar:3.1.4:provided
[INFO] |  \- org.neo4j:neo4j-consistency-check:jar:3.1.4:provided
[INFO] |     +- (org.neo4j:neo4j-kernel:jar:3.1.4:provided - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |     +- (org.neo4j:neo4j-lucene-index:jar:3.1.4:provided - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |     +- org.neo4j:neo4j-command-line:jar:3.1.4:provided
[INFO] |     |  +- (org.neo4j:neo4j-kernel:jar:3.1.4:provided - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |     |  \- (org.neo4j:neo4j-collections:jar:3.1.4:provided - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |     +- org.neo4j:neo4j-dbms:jar:3.1.4:provided
[INFO] |     |  +- (org.neo4j:neo4j-kernel:jar:3.1.4:provided - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |     |  +- (org.neo4j:neo4j-graphdb-api:jar:3.1.4:provided - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |     |  +- (org.neo4j:neo4j-command-line:jar:3.1.4:provided - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |     |  +- (org.neo4j:neo4j-collections:jar:3.1.4:provided - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |     |  +- (org.neo4j:neo4j-io:jar:3.1.4:provided - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |     |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-import-tool:jar:3.1.4:provided
[INFO] |     |  |  +- (org.neo4j:neo4j-kernel:jar:3.1.4:provided - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |     |  |  \- (org.neo4j:neo4j-lucene-index:jar:3.1.4:provided - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |     |  \- org.apache.commons:commons-compress:jar:1.12:provided
[INFO] |     \- (org.neo4j:neo4j-io:jar:3.1.4:provided - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- com.graphaware.neo4j:recommendation-engine:jar:3.1.4.49.11:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.graphaware:recommendation-engine:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.21:compile
[INFO] +- org.neo4j.driver:neo4j-java-driver:jar:1.5.0:test
[INFO] +- com.graphaware.neo4j:common:jar:3.1.4.49:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.esotericsoftware:kryo:jar:3.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.esotericsoftware:reflectasm:jar:1.10.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:5.0.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.esotericsoftware:minlog:jar:1.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:2.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- (commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.9:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.10)
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.3.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- (commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- com.eaio.uuid:uuid:jar:3.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.10:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.6.5:compile
[INFO] +- org.json:json:jar:20170516:compile
[INFO] +- javax:javaee-web-api:jar:6.0:provided
[INFO] +- org.projectlombok:lombok-maven-plugin:jar:1.16.14.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.projectlombok:lombok:jar:1.16.14:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.sonatype.plexus:plexus-build-api:jar:0.0.7:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:1.5.8:compile
[INFO] +- redis.clients:jedis:jar:2.9.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.commons:commons-pool2:jar:2.4.2:compile
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.12:test
[INFO] |  \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] +- org.assertj:assertj-core:jar:3.8.0:compile
[INFO] \- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17:compile
```

I have elasticsearch 6.2.4 which uses lucene 7.2.1 and neo4j 3.1.4 which uses lucene 5.5.0. Now the problem is even if I upgrade neo4j to 3.4.0 (latest) it will still use lucene 5.5.5. In that case upgrade will also not solve the problem. Now if I want to downgrade elasticsearch, its lowest version available in maven central uses lucene 6.2.0. So downgrade will also not work. How should I tackle this problem?

Comment: Looks like incompatible jar Versions of lucene and elasticsearch

Comment: When i am running mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose, it shows me two instances of lucene.

Comment: Than remove one

Comment: Can you help me which one should I delete? I have edited my question details.

Comment: i would remove the older one

Comment: I have elasticsearch 6.2.4 which uses lucene 7.2.1 and neo4j 3.1.4 which uses lucene 5.5.0. Now the problem is even if I upgrade neo4j to 3.4.0 (latest) it will still use lucene 5.5.5. In that case upgrade will also not solve the problem. Now if I want to downgrade elasticsearch, its lowest version available in maven central uses lucene 6.2.0. So downgrade will also not work. How should I tackle this problem?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171949/discussion-between-darshil-babel-and-jens).